# How should i generate a list dynamically using input?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How should i generate a list of names using input data (marked with green in image)

Please check Image for example.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(B2&" "&B3&" "&TOCOL(B4:N4,1)&" "&TOROW(B5:N5,1))
```

---

Comment: Thanx this worked, saved me tone of time and got a new formula to study.

Comment: @ElCalvin glad to know that =)